# Member initialization list for smart pointer to user-defined struct

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, initialization, smart-pointers

Here's the following program. It's just a rectangle being made based on 2 points. My problem is the Rectangle constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


class Point { // class for representing points
public:
    Point(int x, int y);

    void setX(int newVal);
    void setY(int newVal);
};

struct RectData { // Point data for a Rectangle
    Point _ulhc; // ulhc = “ upper left-hand corner”
    Point _lrhc; // lrhc = “ lower right-hand corner”
};

class Rectangle {
public:
    Rectangle(Point ulhc, Point lrhc) :
        _pData->_ulhc(ulhc), _pData->_lrhc(lrhc)
    {}

    Point & upperLeft() const { return _pData->_ulhc; }
    Point & lowerRight() const { return _pData->_lrhc; }

private:
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<RectData> _pData;
};

int main()
{
    Point coord1(0, 0);
    Point coord2(100, 100);
    const Rectangle rec(coord1, coord2); // rec is a const rectangle from
                                        // (0, 0) to (100, 100)
    rec.upperLeft().setX(50); // now rec goes from
                            // (50, 0) to (100, 100)!

    return 0;
}
```

As it seems i don't do the initialization properly. MSVC gives me error `expected a '(' or a '{'`. I'm confused here. How to i properly initialize the `_pData` structure through this constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize `_pData` itself, not its members. e.g.

```
Rectangle(Point ulhc, Point lrhc) :
    _pData(new RectData{ulhc, lrhc})
{}
```